# Creating TCP Server using fsockopen?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

My web hosting company is allowing only fsockopen function to create sockets. I am building an Android Application that needs a TCP Server for transferring message. So my question is it posible to build a TCP Server with fsockopen and not using socket_create?. Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fsockopen()` creates client sockets *only*. There is no way to create a listening socket with that function.

The only ways to create listening (server) TCP sockets in PHP are with the [Streams extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) (see [`stream_socket_server()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-server.php))  - you may find that this is available as well - and the [Sockets extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php), which is less likely to be available.

Even if you can create a listening socket you may find you are unable to do anything useful with it unless you have control over the server's firewall, amongst other things.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, since `fsockopen` can only be used to initiate a connection.

If you insist on using a non-HTTP TCP connection, you could let the server connect back to your client. But this would break on clients behind (NAT) firewalls.

Otherwise, you could simply use HTTP, which at least allows for streaming from server to client. (by disabling output buffering, and maybe needing some extra `flush` calls)